# C++ macros initialize a variable declared in .h from .cpp

Tags: c++

Im trying to load a library based on the operating system this is what I made so far. Although I don't understand why do I get the following error in the .cpp file for the vulkan_lib variable: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier".

.cpp file:

```
#include "vulkan_commons.h"

namespace vk {
    #if defined _WIN32
        vulkan_lib = LoadLibrary(L"vulkan-1.dll");
    #elif defined __linux
        vulkan_lib = dlopen("libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW);
    #endif
}
```

.h file:

```
#ifndef VULKAN_COMMONS_H
#define VULKAN_COMMONS_H

namespace vk {

#if defined _WIN32
    #include <Windows.h>
    #define LoadFunction GetProcAddress
    #define OS_LIB       HMODULE
#elif defined __linux
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    #define LoadFunction dlsym
    #define OS_LIB       void*
#else
    #error
#endif

OS_LIB vulkan_lib;

}

#endif
```

Comment: You never told the compiler the *type* of `vulkan_lib`. `auto vulkan_lib = ... ` would probable do here. Or, if you prefer, name the actual type explicitly.

Comment: What does that macro mess boil down to? Also, which platform and with which macros do you compile?

Comment: Please post a *complete* example.  The code you've posted shouldn't compile on any platform because of undeclared functions, and probably a few other reasons.

Comment: If boost is allowable, they provide an abstraction layer for this...
 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## in the header:

```
extern OS_LIB vulkan_lib;
```

You need `extern` so that `vulkan_lib` is not defined in every TU

## in the cpp:

```
OS_LIB vulkan_lib = ...
```

You need to make it a definition